# Moving contents between containers without innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a nested `<ul>` inside a (hidden) `<aside id="idDetails>`. How to make  the ul move from within the aside and place it in a `<div id="projectSide">`, not using innerHTML?  both plain javascript and jquery please...

Comment: Did you try `$('#idDetails ul').appendTo('#projectSide')` append & appendTo attaches objects to new dom element while dteaching from existing position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and do this both ways off the top of my head.

jQuery:

```
$('#idDetails').find('ul').appendTo('#projectSide');
```

Javascript:

```
var node = document.getElementById('idDetails').firstElementChild,
    parent = node.parentNode;

parent.removeChild(node);

document.getElementById('projectSide').appendChild(node);
```

Not entirely sure about the vanilla JS one, but feel pretty confident on the jQuery one.

Just to satisfy my curiosity, [here is a jsFiddle to show both working](http://jsfiddle.net/YT4sm).

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ul = $('aside ul');
$ul.detach();
$('#projectSide').append($ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `detach()` because `append()` & `appendTo()` attaches existing objects to new position after detaching from old position.

```
$('#idDetails ul').appendTo('#projectSide') //is enough.
```

Comment: i actually checked it, i didnt know `.appendTo` moved, i always assume it cloned. learned something new, thanks man!